# Is disabling landscape mode unforgivable?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Our application could support landscape mode without any problem, but it is such a pain that we are thinking about **forcing portrait mode**.

**Question: Is it BAD?**

The main problem is that changing orientation generates **random crashes** on many screens. Avoiding those crashes would potentially allow us to spend more time on the core aspects of the app. Will the same crashes happen when users switch apps anyway?

Also, are there landscape-oriented devices where our app will become useless?

Comment: If you don't understand why it is crashing, forcing portrait is not a good solution.  Use logcat, figure out why its crashing, fix it!

Comment: it is most likely a design problem in your app that's causing the crashes. it might be worth it to take the time to fix the bug as it could possibly manifest itself in other situations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one area that might be unforgivable.

If a user interacts a lot with your app using a virtual keyboard, you should be vary of one thing:

There are emerging Android phones with a sliding physical keyboard that's meant to be used only in landscape mode. An example of such a device is a [HTC G1](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&q=htc+g1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=univ&ei=qhYSTe25C8-u8QOWo_mGBw&sa=X&oi=image_result_group&ct=title&resnum=4&ved=0CEMQsAQwAw&biw=1045&bih=681).

Since such Androids are usually a premium, their users are very proud of having a physical keyboards. And if your app doesn't allow them to use their keyboard when they can use it, they **will** hate your guts for it and they might even give you negative ratings on Android app. market. Yes, it sounds cruel, but that's life.

Otherwise, having a portrait mode only application that runs well and isn't buggy is more than acceptable.

Moral of the story: try to make as many of your customers happy as possible. You won't always succeed, but you might fail if you piss even a minority of them off.

Answer (score 2):

An unstable app or an app with a poorly thought out, landscape-unfriendly UI is much worse than an app with is limited to portrait.

There are probably some devices where a portrait-only application would be unwieldy, but the majority would handle it ok. Your best bet is to limit the orientation until the Android landscape or your business priorities make it more important to support those devices.

Answer (score 1):

The crashes are probably caused by the activity restarting when changing orientation. With a configuration change you can prevent that without forcing the app to be in portrait mode all the time. Add the config changes line and it will prevent the activity from restarting.

```
<activity 
android:name=".active.help.HelpMenu" 
android:label="@string/help_string"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
```

Comment: you must also include the overridden `onConfigurationChanged` method in this activity

Comment: That doesn't fix anything, that just hides whatever the real problem is so it doesn't happen as often.  There are plenty of other configuration changes that the application can encounter.  The solution is to just fix the crashes in the app, not hide them or make them happen less often.

Comment: @hackbod - I agree with you, but his initial note said that they did not had the time or resources to fix the problem and they are looking into locking the application in portrait mode. I prefer to made this configuration change instead of locking orientation.

Comment: +1 We implemented this solution and it seems to work quite well :-) Now should I accept as an answer the popular answer or this one? :-/ We will do a lot of testing first, to see if it is a good solution. Thanks a lot!